# Shouldn't this power function return 12 when fed $2^4$?

Tags: javascript, math

I'm learning JavaScript, and one of the exercises was to write a power function. I should also learn math because this will surely sound stupid.

I know intuitively that $2 ^ 4 = 16$ since $2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 16$. But reading through the function, it appears that it should return 12, not 16.

If we plug the numbers in, it should look like this: $$2 * (2 * (4 - 1)) = 12$$

```
var power = function( base, exponent ) {
  if ( exponent === 0 ) return 1;
  return base * power( base, exponent - 1 );
};
power(2,4);
===> 16
```

Obviously I must be reading the function wrong. But how?

Comment: This is an example of basic tail recursion, if you are interested.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is correctly written and you could start by analyzing the result of the function as the recursion advances and the exponent decreases.

1. Parameters: 2, 4. Result: 2 * power (2, 3) = 2 * 8 = 16.
2. Parameters: 2, 3. Result: 2 * power (2, 2) = 2 * 4 = 8.
3. Parameters: 2, 2. Result: 2 * power (2, 1) = 2 * 2 = 4.
4. Parameters: 2, 1. Result: 2 * power (2, 0) = 2 * 1 = 1.
5. Parameters: 2, 0. Result: 1.

Hope that was helpful.

Comment: I get it. The function is calling itself over and over! Great thanks! That was really helpful!

Comment: Yes, that's actually one of the basic principles of recursion.

Answer (score 1):

This recursively returns 16.  If $function$ is represented by $f$:

f(2, 4)=2*f(2, 3)=\dots=2*2*2*2*f(2, 0)=2*2*2*2*1=16

More generally,

f(a, b)=a*...*a*1 <- n times.

Comment: I'd give you a vote, but I can't vote up. I definitely need to work on my math because this is a little over my head $2∗2∗2∗2∗f(2,0)$ as in I can't see how we arrived at that from $2*f(2,3)$.

Comment: @Elmer Remember, $$f(base, exponent)=base*f(base, exponent-1)$$ from the code.  This recursion continues until we get $f(2, 0)$, which, from the code, equals 1.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to consider how the function behaves, beginning from the end.

So when the exponent equals $0$ it will return $1$, this will be taken times the base, and all of this will again be multiplied by the base, and so on, so:

$$
(((2^0*2)*2)*2)\ldots)*2
$$

Answer (score 0):

The key is **recursion**.

```
power(2,4)
   = 2 * power(2,3)
   = 2 * (2 * power(2,2))
   = 2 * (2 * (2 * power(2,1)))
   = 2 * (2 * (2 * (2)))
   = 16
```

`power` calls itself with a smaller exponent, which calls itself etc until the exponent is 1, for which the answer is just the base.